# Show/hide closest div using checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I have multiple sets of checkboxes that show/hide a div based on which checkbox is checked. This can be done with IDs but I will have multiple sets of these on the same page and need a more generic selector such as a class or selecting closest elements to the checkbox.

Maybe someone knows why this is not selecting correctly or knows a better way?
http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/h3rh7/

```
$('.check-hide-show-content').hide(); // hide all content divs

// begin show/hide
$('.check-hide-show input:checkbox').click(function () {

    $(this).parent().next('.check-hide-show-content').show();


    $(".check-hide-show input[type='checkbox']").not(this).prop("checked", false); // uncheck the other checkbox when this is checked
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pretty simple:

```
$('.check-hide-show-content').hide(); // hide all content divs

// begin show/hide
$('.check-hide-show input:checkbox').change(function () {
    $('.check-hide-show-content').hide().eq($(this).index('.check-hide-show input:checkbox')).show();
    $(".check-hide-show input[type='checkbox']").not(this).prop("checked", false); // uncheck the other checkbox when this is checked
});
```

Comment: this first hides them all, then finds the 0 based element by the eq() using the index of the checkbox clicked that matches.  You have to get the group inside the index as they are all inside other elements, and the "this" finds that one checked.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the html `data attributes` on the inputs, and targeting the divs via id? I've thrown together a quick example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mRZYf/

Comment: Again, can't use ids. Think 50 sets of these being dynamically written.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the client can only check one element, you can use input type radio.

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="check" id="radio1"></input>
<input type="radio" name="check" id="radio2"></input>
</form>
```

Make sure you give the radios which belongs together have the same name!

Comment: Not an option. Required to use checkboxes so no content is shown until user selects an option.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you're trying for - http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/VL7Vx/1/

```
$('.check-hide-show-content').hide(); // hide all content divs

// begin show/hide
$('.check-hide-show input:checkbox').click(function () {
   $('.check-hide-show-content').hide(); // hide all content divs
    $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
    $(".check-hide-show input[type='checkbox']").not(this).prop("checked", false); // uncheck the other checkbox when this is checked
});
```

Note that I have made changes to your markup as well, by adding to the content divs, new css classes (`option1` and `option2`) that follow the values in the checkboxes. This is one way of tying  the checkboxes to their corresponding divs.

In your code, you were trying to get to the div from the checkbox using '$(this).parent().next('.check-hide-show-content')' which will not succeed because the content divs are not at the level specified by that selector.

Comment: Not really. There will be multiple sets of these. check updated fiddle. so using IDs or value selectors is not really an option. Need to select next closest div to isolate on this set.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to use CSS if your checkbox is the closest sibling.

Example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ks7anbef/)

Example HTML

```
<label>Show Div A? : </label>
<input type="checkbox">
<div>I'm Div A</div><br>

<label>Show Div B? : </label>
<input type="checkbox">
<div>I'm Div B</div><br>

<label>Show Div C? : </label>
<input type="checkbox">
<div>I'm Div C</div><br>
```

Example CSS

```
div {
  display: none;
}

input:checked + div {
  display: block;
}
```